# How to pretty print dictionary returned by robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn.get_variables

Tags: log4j, listener, robotframework, jython-2.5

Jython v2.5
RobotFramework v2.7.5
Log4j v1.2.16

I have a Jython script as a [listener](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#using-listener-interface) that logs the `variables` dictionary but it is not pretty-printed by [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module as it does with `attributes` dictionary.

I am using [BuiltIn().get_variables()](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.7.6/autodoc/robot.libraries.html#robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn.get_variables) function to get the variables dictionary as:

```
def start_suite(self, name, attributes):
    self.LOGGER.info('<<<start_suite>>>')        
    self.LOGGER.debug('variables @ start suite: %s' % pprint.pformat(BuiltIn().get_variables()))
        self.LOGGER.debug('attributes @ start suite: %s' % pprint.pformat(attributes))
```

but this is the output in the logs:

```
2013-05-29 08:03:11,493 [51a618afdf08ff6296260098] DEBUG [NativeMethodAccessorImpl] - variables scoped at start suite: {'${outputdir}': u'/mypath/', '${outputfile}': 'NONE', '${reportfile}': 'NONE', '${none}': None, '${prevtestmessage}': '', '${suitemetadata}': {}, '${suitedocumentation}': '', '${\\n}': '\n', '${/}': '/', '${true}': True, '${:}': ':', '${suitesource}': u'/mypath/source', '${space}': ' ', u'${environment}': u'sit', '${suitename}': u'MySuite', '${debugfile}': 'NONE', '${null}': None, '${logfile}': 'NONE', '${prevteststatus}': '', '${tempdir}': u'/tmp', '${execdir}': u'mypath3', '${prevtestname}': '', '${false}': False, '@{empty}': (), '${empty}': ''}
2013-05-29 08:03:11,499 [51a618afdf08ff6296260098] DEBUG [NativeMethodAccessorImpl] - attributes @ start suite: {'doc': '',
 'longname': u'BcvDocumentImageRequestTest',
 'metadata': {},
 'source': u'/robotRoot/MyTest',
 'starttime': '20130529 08:03:11.224',
 'suites': [u'MyTest', u'MyTest'],
 'tests': [],
 'totaltests': 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe, and is [stated in the docs](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variables) (albeit ambiguously), `BuiltIn().get_variables()` does not return a dictionary, but a dictionary-like object - to pretty-print you will have to get a dictionary from it:

```
dict(BuiltIn().get_variables().items())
```

Comment: @Ghasfarost Oh actually - I'm not sure if the dictionary comprehension works until 2.6, but after some debugging into one of my test cases I cha see what I've gone to way too much trouble - I've amended the answer